# Not getting the name and other information of my friend who is also using the same app using facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to fetch the information about my friends who are also logged in (or using) the app using facebook , for that i am using graph api . But i am not getting relevant information . Can anyone please help me out on that .

I went through the facebook developer docs and tried many option but it didn't helped .

```
//Request 
    FB.api(
"/{app-id}",  // app-id for the application
{
    "fields": "context.fields(friends_using_app)"
},
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
```

);

Using this when i am trying to fetch the information i am getting output like this 
Not getting the name and other information of my friend who is also using the same app using facebook login .

Comment: //Response
 {
  "context": {
    "friends_using_app": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 1
      }
    },
    "id": "YXBwbGljYXRpb25fY29udGV4dDoyMzc0MTk2MDc2MTM4MjU2"
  },
  "id": "2374196076138256"
}

Comment: I have pasted the response for the same as well .

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct code to get all friends who authorized the App too:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', (response) => {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
```